# Как с помощью библиотеки jsPDF корректно отобразить в pdf файле русскоязычный текст?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, utf-8, pdf

С помощью метода doc.text() пытаюсь добавить русскоязычный текст, но вместо него в pdf файле выводятся цифры и случайные символы, хотя с английским и немецкоязычным текстом все правильно выводится. В интернете внятного ответа на этот вопрос не нашел, но вроде как сказано что эта библиотека не поддерживает utf-8. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы необходимо обратится к [официальной инструкции ***jsPDF*** на **github**](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF#use-of-unicode-characters--utf-8).

> 14 стандартных шрифтов в **PDF** ограничены кодовой страницей **ASCII**. Если
> вы хотите использовать **UTF-8**, вам нужно интегрировать собственный
> шрифт, который предоставляет необходимые глифы. ***jsPDF*** поддерживает
> **.ttf-файлы**. Поэтому, если вы хотите, например, иметь китайский текст в
> своем **PDF-файле**, ваш шрифт должен иметь необходимые китайские глифы.
> Итак, проверьте, поддерживает ли ваш шрифт нужные глифы, иначе он
> будет отображать искаженные символы вместо правильного текста.
>
> Чтобы добавить шрифт в ***jsPDF***, используйте наш конвертер шрифтов в
> [/fontconverter/fontconverter.html](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html). Конвертер шрифтов создаст **js-файл** с
> содержимым предоставленного **ttf-файла** в виде строки в кодировке **base64**
> и дополнительным кодом для ***jsPDF***. Вам просто нужно добавить этот
> сгенерированный **js-файл** в свой проект. После этого вы готовы
> использовать метод **setFont** в своем коде и писать текст в кодировке
> **UTF-8**.
>
> В качестве альтернативы вы можете просто загрузить содержимое файла
> ***.ttf** в виде двоичной строки с помощью **fetch** или **XMLHttpRequest** и добавить шрифт в файл **PDF**:

```
const doc = new jsPDF();

const myFont = ... // загрузить файл шрифта *.ttf в виде двоичной строки 

// добавить шрифт в jsPDF 
doc.addFileToVFS("MyFont.ttf", myFont);
doc.addFont("MyFont.ttf", "MyFont", "normal");
doc.setFont("MyFont");
```